# React Native fetch html different results on Android and iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, web-scraping, fetch, cheerio

Could someone explain to me why the response of fetch is different when I do tests on android and when I do the same on iphone? This is causing me problems when extracting the text to be used by the cheerio library.

In android I can extract the data perfectly which does not happen on iPhone, what am I doing wrong or what am I losing?

Thank you very much for any wise response.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import { View } from "native-base";

export default function SearchLinkText() {
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState("");
  const cheerio = require("react-native-cheerio");

  async function loadHTML() {
    const searchUrl =
      "https://www.amazon.es/Bear-Village%C2%AE-Billetera-Magn%C3%A9tico-Plegable/dp/B0834Z8V2V/ref=sr_1_8?
__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=funda+galaxy&qid=1579629120&s=kitchen&sr=1-8";
    const response = await fetch(searchUrl); // fetch page


    const htmlString = await response.text(); // get response text

    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlString, { decodeEntities: false }); // parse HTML string

    console.log('Full HTML:' + htmlString)

    console.log(
      "Title: " +
        $("h1.a-size-large span.a-size-large")
          .html()
          .trim()
    );
    console.log(
      "Price: " +
        $("div.a-section div.feature span.a-size-medium.a-color-price")
          .html()
          .trim()
    );
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        margin: 20
      }}
    >
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1, width: 250 }}
        placeholder="Paste Link"
        onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
        value={value}
      />
      <Button title="Get" onPress={loadHTML} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Android response (Console.log):**

console.log('Full HTML:' + htmlString) *first 30 lines*:

```
<!doctype html><html class="a-no-js" data-19ax5a9jf="dingo">
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript">var ue_t0=ue_t0||+new Date();</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.ue_ihb = (window.ue_ihb || window.ueinit || 0) + 1;
if (window.ue_ihb === 1) {
var ue_hob=+new Date();
var ue_id='3K2TJQ58BVNQN3K7EHVJ',
ue_csm = window,
ue_err_chan = 'jserr-rw',
ue = {};
(function(d){var e=d.ue=d.ue||{},f=Date.now||function(){return+new Date};e.d=function(b){return f()-(b?0:d.ue_t0)};e.stub=function(b,a){if(!b[a]){var c=[];b[a]=function(){c.push([c.slice.call(arguments),e.d(),d.ue_id])};b[a].replay=function(b){for(var a;a=c.shift();)b(a[0],a[1],a[2])};b[a].isStub=1}};e.exec=function(b,a){return function(){try{return b.apply(this,arguments)}catch(c){ueLogError(c,{attribution:a||"undefined",logLevel:"WARN"})}}}})(ue_csm);

ue.stub(ue,"log");ue.stub(ue,"onunload");ue.stub(ue,"onflush");

(function(d,e){function h(f,b){if(!(a.ec>a.mxe)&&f){a.ter.push(f);b=b||{};var c=f.logLevel||b.logLevel;c&&c!==k&&c!==m&&c!==n&&c!==p||a.ec++;c&&c!=k||a.ecf++;b.pageURL=""+(e.location?e.location.href:"");b.logLevel=c;b.attribution=f.attribution||b.attribution;a.erl.push({ex:f,info:b})}}function l(a,b,c,e,g){d.ueLogError({m:a,f:b,l:c,c:""+e,err:g,fromOnError:1,args:arguments},g?{attribution:g.attribution,logLevel:g.logLevel}:void 0);return!1}var k="FATAL",m="ERROR",n="WARN",p="DOWNGRADED",a={ec:0,ecf:0,
pec:0,ts:0,erl:[],ter:[],mxe:50,startTimer:function(){a.ts++;setInterval(function(){d.ue&&a.pec<a.ec&&d.uex("at");a.pec=a.ec},1E4)}};l.skipTrace=1;h.skipTrace=1;h.isStub=1;d.ueLogError=h;d.ue_err=a;e.onerror=l})(ue_csm,window);

ue.stub(ue,"event");ue.stub(ue,"onSushiUnload");ue.stub(ue,"onSushiFlush");

var ue_url='/Bear-Village%C2%AE-Billetera-Magn%C3%A9tico-Plegable/dp/B0834Z8V2V/ref=sr_1_8/uedata/unsticky/262-7660088-5537506/NoPageType/ntpoffrw',
ue_sid='262-7660088-5537506',
ue_mid='A1RKKUPIHCS9HS',
ue_sn='www.amazon.es',
ue_furl='fls-eu.amazon.es',
ue_surl='https://unagi-eu.amazon.com/1/events/com.amazon.csm.nexusclient.prod',
ue_navtiming=1,
ue_fcsn=1,
ue_isrw=true,
ue_fpf='//fls-eu.amazon.es/1/batch/1/OP/A1RKKUPIHCS9HS:262-7660088-5537506:3K2TJQ58BVNQN3K7EHVJ$uedata=s:',
ue_qsl=2000,
```

**iOS response (Console.log):**

console.log('Full HTML:' + htmlString) *first 30 lines*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir=ltr >
<head>
<title>Bear Village┬« Funda para Samsung Galaxy S9 Plus, Billetera Carcasa de Cuero con TPU Tapa Interna, Cierre Magn├®tico, Soporte Plegable, Azul:Amazon</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.amazon.es/Bear-Village%C2%AE-Billetera-Magn%C3%A9tico-Plegable/dp/B0834Z8V2V" />
<meta content="Bear Village┬« Funda para Samsung Galaxy S9 Plus, Billetera Carcasa de Cuero con TPU Tapa Interna, Cierre Magn├®tico, Soporte Plegable, Azul,Bear Village" name="keywords" /><meta content="Amazon Bear Village┬« Funda para Samsung Galaxy S9 Plus, Billetera Carcasa de Cuero con TPU Tapa Interna, Cierre Magn├®tico, Soporte Plegable, Azul" name="description" />
</head>
<body>
<a name="top"></a>
<center>Amazon.es</center>
<b id="product-title">Bear Village┬« Funda para Samsung Galaxy S9 Plus, Billetera Carcasa de Cuero con TPU Tapa Interna, Cierre Magn├®tico, Soporte Plegable, Azul</b>
<br />
<center>
<a href="/gp/aw/d/B0834Z8V2V/ref=mw_dp_img?is=m&qid=1579629120&sr=1-8&vs=1"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71FVhkVbb1L._SL110_.jpg" width="110" id="detailImg" height="110" border="0" /></a>
<br />
<font size="-1">
<a href="/gp/aw/d/B0834Z8V2V/ref=mw_dp_img_2?in=2&qid=1579629120&sr=1-8&vs=1">M├ís im├ígenes</a>
</font>
</center>
<form method="post"
id="addToCart8"
action="/gp/aw/c/ref=mw_dp_buy_pre"
class="a-nostyle button-form">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="B0834Z8V2V" /><input type="hidden" name="o" value="add" /><input type="hidden" name="oid" value="cBUmTruT542F5hkooRpkmtAVtdu3nKf5%2B1E%2BL4odyuwVf3sPoVEX2B1z9QZMxup6GU1URiR4yogV7Zb8zow0r9EWiLbaWYclqxMECJLW9hRrg38qlbpYuIs7KCpKNs%2FAV3IEndaiNnJC%2BUSwIBtYaITk8udEksGz" /><input type="hidden" name="qid" value="1579629120" /><input type="hidden" name="sr" value="1-8" /><input type="hidden" name="verificationSessionID" value="258-0382502-3749862" />
<center>
<input
name="addToCart"
class="cartButton"
type="submit"
value="A├▒adir preventa a la cesta"
```

Comment: The two things that may be happening here, off the top of my head, is that you could be experiencing an AB test on the Amazon page you're requesting, or the request headers differ between platforms and so Amazon is serving a different version of the page based on one of those.

Comment: The first point discarded since I did countless tests and all with the same result, the second point is the one that seems most valid but I would be more inclined to deduce that it could be related to some security policy that iOS could have

Comment: @jasonmerino after reading your analysis, I immediately did a test with a random site and the results were identical, which means you're right, for some reason Amazon provides 2 different versions, the problem is that the iOS version, unlike the Android, is extremely "poor and basic", lacks valid tags and styles that make my goal impossible.

Any hypothesis of why this happens and how can it be solved?

Comment: As to why it happens, it's probably a business decision at some level to make the responses different. Could be style related, could be that they want to show entirely different content (maybe advertising something that only matters to users on a particular platform). 

As for solving the issue, you could try to hardcode all the request headers that get sent by default on the Android request into your `fetch` call and see if it will return the same response even on iOS as it does on Android.